# Elasticsearch query_string hit field

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to retrieve the hit field name using the following query?

```
"query": {
  "query_string": {
     "query": "the quick brown fox"
  }
}
```

The documentation says

"Defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to _all."

But what I need is the correct hit field name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) to see which fields matched your query

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "the quick brown fox"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": false
  }
}
```

This query will return `fields` in the `highlight` section that matched your query

Comment: is it possible to get only the field name without the content?

Comment: I dont think so,`highlighting` is the only option.